# How to filter duplicate system messages from fsnotify

Tags: go, go-fsnotify

I used "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify" to listen for file changes, but how should I filter some messages too many times?

```golang
func Listener() {
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer watcher.Close()
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event, ok := <-watcher.Events:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
                log.Println("event:", event.Name, event.Op)

                // Writing in this way reduces some messages:
                if event.Op&fsnotify.Rename == fsnotify.Rename {
                    // do ...
                } else if event.Op&fsnotify.Create == fsnotify.Create {
                    // do ...
                } else if event.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                    // do ...
                } else if event.Op&fsnotify.Remove == fsnotify.Remove {
                    // do ...
                }
            case _, ok := <-watcher.Errors:
                if !ok {
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()
    
    err = watcher.Add("e:/.../demo")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    <-done
}
```

For example, write, create events occur several times, and I have found that the official bug has been repaired, but it does not seem to be fully resolved

```
2022/12/12 21:00:55 event: e:\...\demo\a.bbb CREATE
2022/12/12 21:00:55 event: e:\...\demo\a.bbb CREATE
2022/12/12 21:00:55 event: e:\...\demo\a.bbb CREATE


2022/12/12 21:01:57 event: e:\...\demo\2.md WRITE
2022/12/12 21:01:57 event: e:\...\demo\2.md WRITE
2022/12/12 21:01:57 event: e:\...\demo\2.md WRITE
2022/12/12 21:01:57 event: e:\...\demo\2.md WRITE
2022/12/12 21:01:57 event: e:\...\demo\2.md WRITE
2022/12/12 21:01:57 event: e:\...\demo\2.md WRITE
2022/12/12 21:01:57 event: e:\...\demo\2.md WRITE
```

How should I filter messages?

############################

```golang
var syncMap sync.Map
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case event, ok := <-watcher.Events:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            fPath := strings.ReplaceAll(event.Name, "\\", "/")
            pathKey, _ := syncMap.Load(fPath)
            if pathKey != 1 {
                // ...
                syncMap.Store(fPath, 1)

                go func() {
                    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
                    syncMap.Delete(fPath)
                }()
            }
        case _, ok := <-watcher.Errors:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}()
```

Comment: How would you know if an event should be ignored or not? Like, did the file really change or was a just a duplicate. In general there are no duplicates, it's likely that your code editor runs several formatters and so on, and actually modifies the file several times. Try to write content to the file using only your shell like `echo foo >> file`, and see if you still get dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library that emits events isn't under your control, you can only change how you *handle* the duplicates.
You could so this with a map[string]bool to keep track of the events you have already seen/processed, so modifying your code you could do this:

```golang
seenMap := make(map[string]bool)
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case event, ok := <-watcher.Events:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            log.Println("event:", event.Name, event.Op)
            _, seen := seenMap[event.Name]
            if !seen {
                // Writing in this way reduces some messages:
                if event.Op&fsnotify.Rename == fsnotify.Rename {
                    // do ...
                } else if event.Op&fsnotify.Create == fsnotify.Create {
                    // do ...
                } else if event.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                    // do ...
                } else if event.Op&fsnotify.Remove == fsnotify.Remove {
                    // do ...
                }
                seenMap[event.Name] = true
            }
        case _, ok := <-watcher.Errors:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}()
```

Comment: Is using sync. map a good choice? I need to filter repeat messages in 2 seconds and I have edited the code

Comment: Sorry not sure about your edited part @zeronofreya, are you asking how you can still avoid processing duplicate events, whilst also using sync.map?

Comment: For example, a file is saved irregularly, if the data in the map is not processed, will cause the code to respond only once, right, so you need to process the data in the map. I chose to no longer accept events within 2 seconds of the code execution. Sync. Map is to avoid some mistakes, but I am inexperienced and don't know if it's reasonable to write like this